# pass variables not in database row through json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a bit of code I would like to pass through my json array that is not contained in the database $row. So i tried to set a custom variable and that didn't work. Is there a way to do this so the below content gets sent through with the array?

Here is what I tried

**PHP**

```
if ($photo_numff == 1) {
    $streamitem_uploadimage_count =" Uploaded new image";
} else if($photo_numff > 1) { 
    $streamitem_uploadimage_count =" Uploaded ".$photo_numff." new images";
} else {
}
```

**JSON array**

```
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$json = array(
    'posts' => array(),
    'count' => $rowcount
);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {    
    $posts[] = array(
        //Post information and ids
        'streamitem_id' => $row['streamitem_id'], // post id
        'streamitem_uploadimage_count' => $streamitem_uploadimage_count,
    );
    $rowcount++; 
}
$json['posts'] = $posts;
echo json_encode($json);
```

I can then take this through my ajax `"+response['streamitem_uploadimage_count']+"`

I have also tried `array_push($json['posts'], array( 'streamitem_uploadimage_count' => $streamitem_uploadimage_count, ) );`but doesn't work

Comment: You can push anything you want on to the array and then encode your JSON.

Comment: so i need `array_push()` to do this?

Comment: Yes, you would use `array_push()`

Comment: Like this?  `array_push($json['posts'], array(
        'streamitem_formholder' => $streamitem_formholder,
        )
    );`

Comment: Doesn't work. Will have to read up about it.

Comment: Anybody got any suggestions please?

Comment: How this "doesn't work" manifest itself? How does the response look like?

Comment: *Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.* ([reference](http://php.net/array_push))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now got this working by adding

```
'streamitem_uploadimage_count' => $streamitem_uploadimage_count
```

within the $Json array also.